# Count occurrence of number and delete line of matches value

Tags: sed, awk, perl

Could I get some help please with my problem? 
I have a file that looks like this (comma separated):

```
A,250,13,820,0,80,201  
B,0,0,0,0,3,0  
C,0,2,1,0,0,0  
D,0,1,105,0,0,10
```

I would like to remove a line if it has 5 true zero values, in this case line B. The end file should look like:

```
A,250,13,820,0,80,201  
C,0,2,1,0,0,0  
D,0,1,105,0,0,10
```

I have difficulties writing the code because `awk` always accounts for all zeros (every line has five zero values, but only line B has five true zeros). Would it be easier with a `perl` script?

Comment: WOOOO, You guys are rockstars. Nailed it. I actually used awk from Glenn, because I am more familiar with it. Totally works. I am sure that the perl solution is as good as the awk ;).  
Thanks a lot. That was soo fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with awk

```
awk -F, '{z=0; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == 0) z++} z != 5' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -aF, -ne 'print unless 5 == grep /^0$/, @F;' < input > output
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `-F` specifies how to split (on a comma in this case)
- `grep` used in scalar context returns the number of hits.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that no other number than `0` starts with `0` in your file and that the first field is not a number like in your sample, you could do:

```
sed -ne 's/,0//5;t' -e p < input > output
```

Note that it deletes those lines that have *at least* 5 zeros.

With your sample again, a:

```
grep ',.*[1-9].*,.*[1-9]'
```

would also do it (searches for two non-zero fields after the first one).

Comment: That grep command is genius. Great example of simplifying a problem by inverting the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'gsub(/,0/, ",0", $0) != 5' data.input
```